# Saving files to server in Cocos2d Javascript Game

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cocos2d-iphone, save

I've been struggling with this for a while and eventually gave up on inpementing any sort of savegame option client side with my cocos2d javascript game (structure based on this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/33028/how-to-make-a-cross-platform-game-with-cocos2d-javascript-tutorial-the-platforms ..  thx Ray .. )
Now i'm trying to find a way to save xml files to a webserver while running my game, firstly in a browser (because that seems the most straightforward way to get this going) and then hopefully later as an app that can access that same webserver.

I have a fair idea how to generate the xml from my array objects and I realise php is my friend when it comes to writing that xml file to disk on the server side.   I've even heard of his pal AJAX that seems to have his contact details : )

My biggest problem at the moment is that the AJAX exampes I have found all use jquery. I realise this might be to simplify the cross browser compatibility issues but I can't fiure out how to add JQuery functionality to the JS in my game (probably stupidly basic or impossible as it will mess up all the bindings, I don't know).  Most examples assume were doing all this straight form a browser script so any help with that would be great.

If jquery is a no go , does anyone have and example of how to send xml data in any format to php?
I'm sure there are enough tutorials out there on how to hande things from there...

If there is a simpler or better way to save savegames locally or on a server using the cocos2d javascript idea i'd be happy to hear it.

Thx..

Edit

I have managed to figure out that the simple answer to the jquery option (at least when deploying to web) is to include jquery at the top of the cocos2d.js file where all the other js files are loaded... might not be a sound option when it comes to porting it all to iphone though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sys.localstorage` is the way to save data.

Comment: Works beautifully once I put turned my objects into strings thank you.